# Inconsistent Android SQLite registers

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a local SQLite database on my Android app. In order to perform some tests, I do some insertions with `values.put(regValues);` `db.insert(register);` `db.close();`. Then, I do some queries with the data and here it when it all gets messy:

The data is stored on a local SQLite database. When I query the data on my Android app with a general statement such as `SELECT * FROM TABLE`, it only retrieves 2 of the 8 inserted registers. This could be an insertion error, but here is the thing:

On Android, the query and the iteration is done the following way:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
        new String[]{TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_ID},
        null,
        null,
        null, null, null, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();

int numberRegs = 0;

while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    numberRegs++;
}

Log.d(LOG_TAG, "numberRegs: " + numberRegs);
```

When I check the registers with [this web debugger](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database), I can see all the 8 inserted registers. To complicate things a bit more, I have tried to download the database `local` on my computer and see if I could see the 8 registers inserted on the database, but I only see 4 of them.

Due to this, I am completely lost because I am not able to know the real state of the local SQLite database. Therefore, my questions are: why does this inconsistency happen and what can I do to fix it in order to see on my queries on Android the 8 registers instead of the current 2?

Comment: When you download the file to your pc do you also download the .db-shm and .db-wal files? How do yo check the number of rows after `SELECT * FROM TABLE`?

Comment: No, I do not download the shm and db-wal files, as I have seen that they are only temporary files. Therefore, the persisted data should be consistent without these files, no? Regarding the last part, I've updated the code snippet checking of the # of rows on Android on the question.

Comment: No they are not only temp files. Download all of them and place them in the same folder and then open the database to inspect it. As for your code, for sure it loses the 1st row because you do moveToFirst() and then moveToNext(). Instead just do `Log.d(LOG_TAG, "numberRegs: " + cursor.getCount());`

Comment: Ok, now the thin is: `cursor.getCount()` returns the 8 registers (which is correct), BUT when I iterate with `while(cursor.moveToNext())` I only get the previous 2 registers. Therefore, how can I iterate through the registers in order to obtain the whole 8 registers that appear with `cursor.getCount()`?

Comment: As it is your code, if you remove `cursor.moveToFirst();` you should see 8 in the Log. Are you sure that you posted the exact code?

Comment: Ok, problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that using `while(cursor.moveToNext())` stops before iterating through all registers. Instead of this, the iteration should be done like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++){
    cursor.moveToNext();
    //Do stuff with cursor info
}
```

Comment: `while(cursor.moveToNext())` stops when `moveToNext()` returns `false` and this happens after the last row or if there are no rows. There is no case that it stops before. I believe that either the problem is inside the loop or something else that you did not post.